# Realm: Not working in Unit-Test

Tags: swift, realm, xctest

I'm using Realm in a Swift project and have a strange behavior. I query for a property within a test from my model. I can see the correct value of the property within a breakpoint, but the test receives an empty string. Any ideas?

Model:

```
func userName()->String{

    if let userData = self.realm.objects(UserData).first{
        return userData.userName
    }
    return "-"
}
```

Test:

```
let userName = userModel.userName()            
XCTAssert(userName == "user@test.com")
```

--> userName is "", but the breakpoint in line  `return userData.userName` says "user@test.com". 
If I replace `return userData.userName` with `return "test"` it is working as expected. So the problem is that the current value inside the realm object is lost when another method is querying it.

If I print userdata.useName I now get "" and If I check the properties of userData the are empty. But if I click on the little (i) on userData I can see all the properties...

```
if let userData = self.realm.objects(UserData).first{

            print("start>")
            print(userData.userName)
            print("<finish")

            return userData.userName
        }
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you saying the assert passes or fails? How do you know userName is ""? And when you include `return "test", the assert will obviously fail, so what are you trying to do?

Comment: I edited my question. I know that the userName is ""  from a breakpoint and the failing test. If my model-method returns "test" I can see "test" within my test breakpoint.

Comment: I think you should `print(userName)` just before the assert to be sure. It may be that your `userData.userName` is an Optional, in which case the string you get from it will be "Optional(whatever)", which will not match with "whatever". Meaning you would need to unwrap it with !. - Actually what I just said is not quite right, but put the print in to be sure what it really has. Since you're returning a string, Realm isn't losing the value - you're outside Realm once you take a string copy of the property.

Comment: please see my latest edit (the last part of my question)

Comment: Is the UserData.swift file in just you app target, or just your test target, or both?

Comment: It is just in the app target

Comment: I'm running out of ideas. It might be worthwhile adding a screen shot of the "little (i)", and add a bounty to the question to get others interested in it. It would also help to give further info on userModel - does it inherit from Object (ie. Realm), and how is it created? And are you using an in-memory Realm or disk? If in-memory, are you calling realm.add for it? If on disk, maybe show it's in Realm Browser

Comment: I'm also unsure how this could be happening. Could you please file an issue, sharing steps to reproduce, at https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/new? Thanks!